# Using a class template that is the member of a class

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

You can have a "shorthand" for a class template from a namespace by only giving the name of the template. However if the class template is in a class, I have to create an alias template and write out all the template parameters and arguments - which is bad for maintainability:

```
namespace mynamespace {
    template<template<class> class T>
    class MyClass;
}

using mynamespace::MyClass; // OK, straight and simple

class MyOuterClass {
public:
    template<template<class> class T>
    class MyInnerClass;
};

// using MyInnerClass = MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass; // error: invalid use of template-name 'MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass' without an argument list

// template<typename... TArgs> // error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class T> class MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass'
// using MyInnerClass = MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<TArgs...>;

template<template<class> class T> // OK, but copying the template parameter list is bad, there should be some "auto" mechanism...
using MyInnerClass = MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<T>;

int main(){}
```

[Run code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f9111c0c44c30fa)

Can I have a "shorthand" for such a template in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

If `MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<>` **only** had ***type*** template parameters, you could use the following *variadic alias template*:

```
template<typename... TArgs>
using MyInnerClass = MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<TArgs...>;
```

However, you still have to provide the *parameter pack* `TArgs`.

---

Assuming C++17, if `MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<>` **only** had ***non-type*** template parameters you could use the following variadic alias template:

```
template<auto... Val>
using MyInnerClass = MyOuterClass::MyInnerClass<Val...>;
```

Comment: Works only if all template parameters are type template parameters. See my edit for a counter-example.

Comment: Maybe `auto...` in c++17? (not sure if that actually works)

Comment: I think C++17's `auto` is only for non-type template parameters.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no such way. To `using` statements which are *used* (no pun intended) to make the definition visible are actually different versions of the same keyword. One is a `using declaration`, and another is an alias for `typedef`. They work differently and provide for different (though some times similarly looking) results.

Comment: So I have to make a trade-off between hiding my templates in a class (as private members) or putting them in a namespace (to make working with them easier by making them eligible for use in using declarations)?